# Adding bounds to curve_fit: Positional arguments error

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

**Trying to perform curve-fitting on a function, using scipy curve_fit:**

```
param_bounds=((-np.inf,-np.inf,0),(np.inf,np.inf,1))
OneCyParams, extras = curve_fit(func,xdata,ydata,bounds=param_bounds)
```

**Resulting error:**

```
    453     if weights is None:
    454         def func_wrapped(params):
--> 455             return func(xdata, *params) - ydata
    456     else:


    457         def func_wrapped(params):

TypeError: OneCycle() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

OneCycle is the function I'm fitting.

This error goes away if I remove the bounds argument. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show how the model fucntion, `func`, is defined? It looks like `func` was written to take in a list of parameters instead of separate arguments for each parameter.

Comment: `def func(Xin,P1):


    modelx = (((Xin ** P1) / ((Xin ** P1) + (1 - Xin) ** P1)))


    return modelx`

Comment: Oops, I see my mistake.  These parameter bounds are for a following function which has three parameters.  I just mindlessly copied it without remembering that this first function has fewer parameters.  I seriously stared at this error for an hour without realizing.  

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was because the relevant func only has one parameter.

Once the param_bounds was appropriately adjusted, the problem resolved.